# Python displays too much curve for logarithmic curve fitting

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, curve-fitting

I'm trying to do a logarithmic curve fitting on boston housing dataset. but the fitted curve is not as good as the fitted curve in excel.

Here is my source code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, y = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Desktop\Programming\My Written Codes\Datasets\Boston.xlsx')['AGE'].to_numpy(), pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Desktop\Programming\My Written Codes\Datasets\Boston.xlsx')['TAX'].to_numpy()


slope, inter = np.polyfit(np.log(X), y, 1)

plt.scatter(X, y, c = 'r', edgecolor = 'k')
plt.plot(X, slope * np.log(X) + inter, c = 'b')
plt.show()
```

And the output is this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zOsJ.jpg)

Can you suggest what can I do to make this plot more pretty?

Thanks!

Comment: Try sorting your data by X-axis position before fitting and plotting: `pd.read_excel('...')['TAX'].sort_values().to_numpy()`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you user Peter Leimbigler :) You fixed my problem!

Comment: @AmirrezaSoltani that's great to hear!